# Best way to define a range table with range of data

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to define a table in which I need to define different number ranges. For example:

```
id min_range max_range
1     0          10
2     11         20
3     21         30
```

now I need to check from C# code if a value falls between a particular range then I need to do a particular task respectively.
Is this the best way to define a particular range in a mysql table? Any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

According to me you are doing best.

one more way can be that we can store in a single field like `0-10`,`11-20`,... But I think that will not be scalable and will be difficult to manage.